# How to group datas in specific condition and how to get minimum data in it

Tags: excel, vba

Having a problem with making a code in vba. First, there are numbers and datas on each row d and e, like number 1~14, 20~39, 48~60 and 84~98. These groups change each time(Randomly). What I want to get is a minimum value of each group. This value should be next to the rows with data. Could you help me with this one?

```
Rowsss = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(3).Row
For i = 10 To Rowsss + 1
If .Cells(i, 4) - .Cells(i - 1, 4) = 1 Then
  n = n + 1
  next i
  if .cells(i,4)-.cells(i-1,4)<>1 then
```

(I'm stuck in here)

```
End If
Next
```

I want to get results like group number and results
ex. 1/14/minimum value

Comment: `Split(.Cells(i, 4) .Value,"~")(0)` will give minimum and `Split(.Cells(i, 4) .Value,"~")(1)` will give maximum

Comment: Also change `.End(3).Row` to `.End(-4162).Row` or to `.End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thanks! I will try what you adviced :)